# Calculation of the Earth Station coordinates in the Earth Fixed Geocentric Coordinate System

Tags: python, elevation, satellite, azimuth

I tried to implement a calculation to determine the Az and El angles needed to point an antenna at a given Earth Station coordinates with respect to a GEO Satellite. The source of the mathematical equations needed is a document from Intelsat which can be found under:

https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/supplemental/IESS_412_Rev_3.pdf

The calculation procedure is described in chapter 2.5

And my code looks like this:

'''

```
import math as m
#import numpy
import mpmath as mp



#Constants

EFc = 1 / 298.257 #flattening constant which recognizes that the polar radius is less than the equatorial radius by
                  #1 part in 298.257
R = 6378.140 #Radius of earth (km)
print("Radius of earth (km)", R, "km")
aGSO= 42164.57  #Circumference of earth(km)
print("Circumference of earth(km)", aGSO, "km")

#Variable Declaration

Pss = float(input("Input Location of Satellite in degrees:")) #Location of geostationary satellite(degrees)
if Pss > 0:
    print("Your input:", Pss,"° East")
else:
    print("Your input:", abs(Pss),"° West")
    
PE= float(input("Input Longitude of ES in degrees:"))   #Longitude of the earth station antenna(degrees)
print("Your input:", PE, "°")
LE= float(input("Input Latitude of ES in degrees:"))    #Latitude of the earth station antenna(degrees)
print("Your input:", LE, "°" )
HS = int(input("If North Hemi input 180:"))




#Calculations

Rs = R / m.sqrt(1-EFc*(2-EFc)*(m.sin(m.radians(LE)))**2)
ho = float(input("Input for height over seaside level in km:"))

Ra = (Rs+ho)*m.cos(m.radians(LE)) #ES radial distance from earth rotation axis

Rz = Rs*((1-EFc)**2)*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) #ES distance above earth equtorial plane

r = aGSO - Rs
rx = aGSO*m.cos(0)*m.cos(m.radians((Pss-PE)))-Ra
ry = aGSO*m.cos(0)*m.sin(m.radians((Pss-PE)))
rz = aGSO*m.sin(0)-Rz
dr_north = -rx*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) + rz*m.cos(m.radians(LE))
dr_zenith = rx*m.cos(m.radians(LE)) + rz*m.sin(m.radians(LE))
SR = m.sqrt(rx**2 + ry**2 + rz**2) #Slantrange in km

Az = m.atan(ry/dr_north) #in Rad

if HS == 180:
    Azd = HS + m.degrees(Az)
else:
    Azd = m.degrees(Az)

ELg = m.degrees(m.atan(dr_zenith/m.sqrt((dr_north**2+ry**2))))


x = ELg + m.degrees(0.589)
a = 0.58804392
a1 = -0.17941557
a2 = 0.29906946 * 10e-1
a3 = -0.25187400 * 10e-2
a4 = 0.82622101 * 10e-4

if ELg > 10.2:
    ELob = ELg + 0.01617 * mp.cot(m.radians(ELg))
elif ELg < 10.2:
    ELob = ELg + a + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3 + a4*x**4


print("Rstation in km:", Rs, "km")
print()
print("Slantrange in km:",SR,"km")
print()
#print("Ra in km:", Ra, "km")
#print("Rz in km:", Rz, "km")
print("Azimuth angle in degrees:", Azd, "°")
print()
#print(rx)
#print(ry)
#print(rz)
#print(dr_north)
#print(dr_zenith)

print("Elevation angle in degrees:", ELob,"°")
```

'''

So far so good but i get a strange error ot lets say unexpected results for a specific input.

For example if i try to point the antenna towards a Satellite with **orbital position 50° West**, then the output looks like:

Circumference of earth(km) 42164.57 km
Input Location of Satellite in degrees:-50
Your input: 50.0 ° West
Input Longitude of ES in degrees:11.66
Your input: 11.66 °
Input Latitude of ES in degrees:48.26
Your input: 48.26 °
If North Hemi input 180:180
Input for height over seaside level in km:0.68
Rstation in km: 6390.059844850744 km

Slantrange in km: 40596.37254163326 km

Azimuth angle in degrees: 248.10660270274292 °

**Elevation angle in degrees: 1471.9705470065662 °**

The Elevation angle is completely out of a reasonable range.

Up to an orbital position of the satellite of **49° West** it works just fine.
Radius of earth (km) 6378.14 km
Circumference of earth(km) 42164.57 km
Input Location of Satellite in degrees:-49
Your input: 49.0 ° West
Input Longitude of ES in degrees:11.66
Your input: 11.66 °
Input Latitude of ES in degrees:48.26
Your input: 48.26 °
If North Hemi input 180:180
Input for height over seaside level in km:0.68
Rstation in km: 6390.059844850744 km

Slantrange in km: 40528.75697667383 km

Azimuth angle in degrees: 247.2745538278463 °

**Elevation angle in degrees: 10.5904943454838 °**

I just do not get it why is this happening. May be someone has a hint for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this line in your code
`x = ELg + m.degrees(0.589)`

Should be changed to :

```
x = ELg + 0.589
```

your Elg is in degrees. 0.589 is also degrees. the function m.degrees(0.589) will try to convert radians to degrees. But in the documentation you provided 0.589 is degrees.

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1):

Like Atanas Atanasov already responded there is the first mistake:

```
x = ELg + m.degrees(0.589)
```

In addition i found another two mistakes in the code:

```
Rz = Rs*((1-EFc)**2)*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) #ES distance above earth equtorial plane
```

it should be:

```
Rz = (Rs*((1-EFc)**2)+ho)*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) #ES distance above earth equtorial plane
```

and the definition of the coefficients should be like this:

```
a2 = 0.29906946 * 1e-1
a3 = -0.25187400 * 1e-2
a4 = 0.82622101 * 1e-4
```

After this adaptations have been done the code is working now as expected.

So the final version looks like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 31 09:57:50 2021

@author: o27503515
"""
import math as m
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp


#Constants

EFc = 1 / 298.257 #flattening constant which recognizes that the polar radius is less than the equatorial radius by
                  #1 part in 298.257
R = 6378.140 #Radius of earth (km)
print("Radius of earth (km)", R, "km")
aGSO= 42164.57  #Circumference of earth(km)
print("Circumference of earth(km)", aGSO, "km")

#Variable Declaration

Pss = float(input("Input Location of Satellite in degrees:")) #Location of geostationary satellite(degrees)
if Pss > 0:
    print("Your input:", Pss,"° East")
else:
    print("Your input:", abs(Pss),"° West")
    
PE= float(input("Input Longitude of ES in degrees:"))   #Longitude of the earth station antenna(degrees)
print("Your input:", PE, "°")
LE= float(input("Input Latitude of ES in degrees:"))    #Latitude of the earth station antenna(degrees)
print("Your input:", LE, "°" )
HS = int(input("If North Hemi input 180:"))




#Calculations

Rs = R / m.sqrt(1-EFc*(2-EFc)*(m.sin(m.radians(LE)))**2)
ho = float(input("Input for height over seaside level in km:"))

Ra = (Rs+ho)*m.cos(m.radians(LE)) #ES radial distance from earth rotation axis

Rz = (Rs*((1-EFc)**2)+ho)*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) #ES distance above earth equtorial plane

r = aGSO - Rs
rx = aGSO*m.cos(0)*m.cos(m.radians((Pss-PE)))-Ra
ry = aGSO*m.cos(0)*m.sin(m.radians((Pss-PE)))
rz = aGSO*m.sin(0)-Rz
dr_north = -rx*m.sin(m.radians(LE)) + rz*m.cos(m.radians(LE))
dr_zenith = rx*m.cos(m.radians(LE)) + rz*m.sin(m.radians(LE))
SR = m.sqrt(rx**2 + ry**2 + rz**2) #Slantrange in km

Az = m.atan(ry/dr_north) #in Rad

if HS == 180: #In case ES is in North Hemisphere
   Azd = HS + m.degrees(Az)
else:
    Azd = m.degrees(Az)

ELg = m.degrees(m.atan(dr_zenith/m.sqrt((dr_north**2+ry**2))))


x = ELg + 0.589 
a0 = 0.58804392
a1 = -0.17941557
a2 = 0.29906946 * 1e-1
a3 = -0.25187400 * 1e-2
a4 = 0.82622101 * 1e-4

if ELg > 10.2:
    ELob = ELg + 0.01617 * mp.cot(m.radians(ELg))
else:
    ELob = ELg + a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3 + a4*x**4


print("Rstation in km: %.2f" % Rs, "km")
print()
print("Slantrange in km: %.2f" % SR,"km")
print()
#print("Ra in km:", Ra, "km")
#print("Rz in km:", Rz, "km")
print("Azimuth angle in degrees: %.2f" % Azd, "°")
print()
#print(rx)
#print(ry)
#print(rz)
#print(dr_north)
#print(dr_zenith)

print("Elevation angle in degrees: %.2f" % ELob,"°")
```